# How to use formControlName in a child component and then get value of it in the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

so basicly I created my own component that is filterable select with option to add new items to the pickListItems. The problem is that I want to have the input value as a formControl but I'm gettin error even when I'm passing `formGroup` to the child.

So example code looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  some stuff here to generate form fields, one of fields is my component with 
  select:
  <app-add-picklist
    [field]="field"
    [formControlName]="field.Label"
    [formGroup]="formGroup">
</app-add-picklist>
<form>
```

And in the `add-picklist` component I have:

```
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
@Input() formControlName: string;
@Input() field: any;
```

and in the ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.formGroup.addControl(this.formControlName, new FormControl());
}
```

And the template (part of all):

```
<input type="text"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Pick one"
   aria-label="Number"
   matInput
   [formControlName]="formControlName"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

So I'm keep getting error

```
No value accessor for form control with name: xxxx. 
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

I understand what it means but dunno how to handle it in this case..

Comment: Why not make `<add-picklist>` a custom form control? There's lots of info about this

Comment: you mean to implement `ControlValueAccessor`?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use a custom `@Input formControlName` since Angular also tries to use it.
If you rename it it would work (same for `formGroup`)

```
@Input() formGroupParent: FormGroup;
@Input() formControlNameParent: string;
```

Then, you can't use `[formControlName]` since the parent form is not in the same HTML code (it's in the parent's).
Instead, use `[formControl]="formGroupParent[formControlNameParent]"`

Also, an input must have a name. Have to add it, and an `*ngIf` since the name is a `@Input()`, and will be null for some milisecs (time between the constructor and the ngOnInit being triggered)...

```
<input *ngIf="formGroupParent && formControlNameParent" 
   type="text"
   [name]="formControlNameParent"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Pick one"
   aria-label="Number"
   matInput
   [formControl]="formGroupParent[formControlNameParent]"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

Comment: Thats weird, now I have `Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute` error even when I try to add name or formControlName attribute inside of the input

Comment: @D.Zet Yup, an Input must have a name. Please see my edit (including `*ngIf` safety)

Comment: Yeah I know, but even with `[name]` set there is an error that says: `Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute` so it's realy weird

Comment: @D.Zet Yes, but did you add an `*ngIf` as I advised ? If yes, can you make a stackblitz repoducing your issue ? There must be something else wrong.